# js: Escape special characters

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

Webapp has, say, comments form.
If user is inputting something like:
"Comment about 'topic" (single quote is not closed)
This brakes `node-postgres` queries.
What is the simplest way to escape/comment-out/convert-to-unicode all the special characters? But at the same time, make it easy to render on the page after all.

For example, backslash would successfully comment-out the single quote. But i'm sure, there are much more special characters, which could break the pg queries. Is there some commonly used script/module to make strings safe?

Comment: Use prepared statements and bind parameters into them. That way you don't need to care about it.

Comment: `Is there some commonly used script/module to make strings safe?` There is [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), as one example.

Comment: @vitaly-t, I don't get it, how does it help me to escape special characters

Comment: @stkvtflw that library does it automatically, as it implements its own query formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`node-postgres` has such method already:
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements